# 3 max flow prove or disprove small questions

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, max-flow, ford-fulkerson, edmonds-karp

The questions are :

[image]

for (a) it seems like it is not true, we can fin an example of the flow growing without e being saturated.

for (b) it seems true, yet i am not sure how to prove it. Maybe because of the
min cut max flow theorm, it was on the min cut so it had to grew.

for (c) it seems false. the flow grew because e changed but e might have not grew by exactly 5.

Comment: This would be more appropriate on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). Can't really get into it right now but... for (a), I think it is true (maybe you could add a counter example)? (b) is false, simply take a graph where you have 2 consecutive saturated edges belonging to 2 min-cuts, if you increase the capacity of one, the other is still saturated (if there is no other edge connected to the inner node). (c) is false, simply because you could have increased `e` by something larger than 5 and saturated another edge.

Comment: This is a homework?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) seems true for me - If you managed to increase the maximum flow, it means that you found a new path from the source to the sink (that did not exist before increasing the edge `e`). So `e` must be in this new path, but if `e` was not saturated before, then the path would have existed in the original graph.

(2) is false. Take a graph like this:

```
s --20-- n --20-- t
```

Where `s` is the source and `t` the sink, there are two min-cuts (`{(s, n)}` and `{(n, t)}`), but increasing either `(s, n)` or `(n, t)` won't change the maximum flow.

(3) is false. Take a graph like this:

```
s --20-- n --25-- t
```

If I increase the capacit of `e = (s, n)` by `10`, then the new maximum flow is `25`, but I did not increase the value of `e` by `5`.

Answer (score 0):

For (1):

> The max-flow of the network has increased from 20 to 30 by increasing the capacity of some edge `e` and we need to prove that `e` must have been saturated before the increase.

Consider, the inverse, that `e` was not saturated before the increase. In this case then there must exist a edge (or group of edges) `e'` where the entire flow through `e` also passes through `e'` and that the max-flow of the network is limited by the capacity through the edge(s) `e'` such that `capacity(e') < capacity(e)` (otherwise `e` would be saturated).

Given this, if we increase `capacity(e)` then we are still in the situation where `capacity(e') < capacity(e)` and the max-flow of the network will be unaffected by the increased capacity.

This is a contradiction (since increasing the capacity of `e` increased the max-flow); so `e` must be saturated *(and you can take it further to note that if `e'` exists then it cannot be saturated for the max-flow to have increased)*.

**For example:**

```
    /-- 10 --\ 
source      node -- 30 -- sink
    \-- 10 --/

        e'           e
```

The graph above demonstrates the contradiction where the max-flow is limited by the capacity of the two edges `e'` from source to node and `e` (from node to sink) is not saturated and increasing `e` will not increase the max-flow.

However,

```
    /-- 15--\ 
source      node -- 20 -- sink
    \-- 15 --/

        e'           e
```

In this graph, `e` is saturated (and `e'` is not saturated`) and increasing the capacity of`e` to 30 (or more) will increase the max-flow of the graph to 30.

For the rest:

- *see [Holt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34672256/1509264)*